# What are the objects call that transform data between layers

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a question about what is the convention for naming objects the transform one object into another.  I swear there was an elegant name for this that I'm forgetting and all my searches just end up with the difference between a DTO and and Entity or Model or DAO or POCO or POJO.

I'm not interested in using Automapper at this point either, I might convert to that later, but the code is there, I just want to name it correctly!

Comment: `what is the convention for naming objects the transform one object into another` Mapping? Mapping Layer?

Comment: Use whatever you want. Later, If you think it should be renamed, (Thans to VS) you can it do it with a few clicks/keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the term `Mapper` used most often, myself. Sometimes "Mapper" ends up being a part of the assembly name and/or namespace, and the class name may be `MyTypeToYourType` or `MyType_YourType`.

In Domain Driven Design, the mapping layer is known as the "Anti-Corruption Layer"--**not** a very elegant name--and sometimes as the "translation layer". (See page 34 of Eric Evans' *[Domain Driven Design Reference](http://domainlanguage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DDD_Reference_2015-03.pdf)* for both.)

In general I'd say use whatever term your brain most easily connects to the meaning, so that when you have to fix something at 3am a year from now, it readily makes sense. And then be consistent with it!

Comment: I'm going with Mapper, thanks for the link to Domain Driven Design Reference, that cemented it in my brain for now.

Answer (score 0):

[Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) uses the term Assembler within the context of DTOs.

Comment: I like this one also, but since I'm going with Mapper for now I marked the answer by A.Franklin as correct.  This could make more sense for the next person who looks at this however!